# Git local repository and recovering files after hard drive crash

Tags: git

I have a local git repository set up on my laptop, and my computer just crashed. I have a copy of the repo folder on dropbox, can I recover my files (on a new hard drive ) somehow? From my understanding that is not how git works (it stores the version differences locally right?) but I saw some other threads on here and wasn't sure anymore.

Comment: On the level of abstraction the commands operate, it stores objects (blobs - snapshots of files, trees - snapshots of directories, commits) and not diffs. However if your repo grows bigger some of the objects might be packed to a different format. As long as the dropbox copy is up-to-date you should be able to recover everything which was committed and staged, as well as files not registered with git. That's assuming there was no curruption of course. If some files (objects, not necessary branches or other things like that) in `.git` were corrupted this will be detected by git client.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the copy on Dropbox is relatively recent (that is, it sync'd the last time you committed in Git), the likelihood of you recovering your most recent changes is zero.

Git is distributed; it works powerfully locally, but you do have to have good backups to ensure that it keeps working in that manner.  Syncing the .git folder to Dropbox is fine, but you would want to ensure that it's relatively up to date, and if you can't do that, then you've unfortunately lost your files.